# Which version of OroCRM is working for oro:migration:load?

Tags: mysql-8.0, php-7.4, orocrm

I'm trying a clean instalation in Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 7.4.3 and mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

```
    $ composer info | grep 'oro/'
oro/calendar-bundle                  4.1.3              Calendar bundle for OroPlatform-based applications.
oro/commerce                         4.1.4              OroCommerce - an open-source Business to Business Commerce application. \nThis package contains bundles and needs to be added as a dependency in an ...
oro/commerce-crm                     4.1.2              OroCRM integration for OroCommerce
oro/crm                              4.1.4              OroCRM
oro/crm-call-bundle                  4.1.3              Oro Call Bundle
oro/crm-dotmailer                    4.1.4              Oro Dotmailer integration
oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle         4.1.1              Oro Google Hangouts integration
oro/crm-magento-embedded-contact-us  4.1.1              OroCRM Magento Embedded Contact Us package
oro/crm-task-bundle                  4.1.3              Oro Task Bundle
oro/crm-zendesk                      4.1.2              OroCRM Zendesk Integration
oro/customer-portal                  4.1.4             
oro/doctrine-extensions              1.2.2              Doctrine Extensions for MySQL and PostgreSQL.
oro/marketing                        4.1.3              Oro Marketing Bundles
oro/oauth2-server                    4.1.3              Oro OAuth 2.0 authorization and resource server for BAP
oro/platform                         4.1.4              Business Application Platform (BAP)
oro/platform-serialised-fields       4.1.1              OroPlatform Serialized Fields
oro/redis-config                     4.1.2              OroRedisConfigBundle
oro/twig-inspector                   1.0.3              Oro Twig Inspector adds the possibility to find twig templates and blocks used for rendering HTML pages faster during development
```

But, When I run ***php bin/console oro:migration:load --force --show-queries***

```
    CREATE TABLE oro_workflow_definition (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, start_step_id INT DEFAULT NULL, label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, related_entity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, entity_attribute_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, steps_display_ordered TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, system TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, priority INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, configuration LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)(DC2Type:array)', exclusive_active_groups LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', exclusive_record_groups LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', created_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime)', updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime)', applications LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', INDEX idx_6f737c368377424f (start_step_id), PRIMARY KEY(name)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
    ERROR: An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE oro_workflow_definition (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, start_step_id INT DEFAULT NULL, label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, related_entity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, entity_attribute_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, steps_display_ordered TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, system TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, priority INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, configuration LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)(DC2Type:array)', exclusive_active_groups LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', exclusive_record_groups LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', created_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime)', updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime)', applications LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:simple_array)(DC2Type:simple_array)', INDEX idx_6f737c368377424f (start_step_id), PRIMARY KEY(name)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'system TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, priority INT' at line 1
```

> In MigrationExecutor.php line 116:
>                                                                                                    Failed migrations:
>   Oro\Bundle\WorkflowBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroWorkflowBundleInstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Mysql 5.7. OroCommerce 4.1.4 is not compatible with Mysql 8.